# Unable to open using mode r: fopen() while uploading file to aws s3 from elastic beanstalk with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have uploaded my codeigniter project to aws elastic beanstalk and i am trying to upload an imagefile and an audio file after the image is done uploading.

Now the image upload is a successful one and below is the code

```
    $path = $_FILES['thumbnail']['name'];
        $file_temp = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_name = time() . "." . $ext;
$file_type = $_FILES['thumbnail']['type'];
$upload_path = 'uploads/thumbnails/';
$s3->putObject(
                array(
                    'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
                    'Key' => $upload_path . $new_name,
                    'SourceFile' => $file_temp,
                    'ContentType' => $file_type,
                    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                    'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD'
                )
            );
```

and for the audio file upload the code sample is as below

```
$path = $_FILES['audio']['name'];
$file_name = "audio_" . time() . "." . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_temp = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['audio']['type'];
$upload_path = 'uploads/audios/';
$s3->putObject(
            array(
                'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
                'Key' => $upload_path . $file_name,
                'SourceFile' => $file_temp,
                'ContentType' => $file_type,
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD'
            )
        );
```

And here is the snippet that executes the 2 upload methods

```
//upload image file
$thumb_upload = $this->upload_thumbnail();
//upload video file
$audio_upload = $this->upload_audio();
```

But i am trying to find out what the error is because if the image upload is a success, why is the audio upload giving an error as

> Error:Unable to open using mode r: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Thanks in advance

Comment: where and how do you use `fopen()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to open using mode r: fopen(): AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663757/unable-to-open-using-mode-r-fopen-aws-elastic-beanstalk)